# State machine in Go

Tags: go

I have a kind of state machine. So I have states:

```
const (
    state1 = iota
    state2
    state3
    exit
)
```

Also, I have a `chan`:

```
stateMachine := make(chan int)
```

I put the first state:

```
stateMachine <- state1
```

And then, I enter in infinite loop like this:

```
for {
   select {
   case state := <- stateMachine:
      switch state {
      case state1: 
         fmt.Println("state1")
         stateMachine <- state2
      case state2: 
         fmt.Println("state2")
         stateMachine <- state3
      case state3: 
         fmt.Println("state3")
         stateMachine <- exit
      case exit:
         fmt.Println("Exit")
         os.Exit(0)
      }
   }
}
```

But it does not work.

https://play.golang.org/p/s5uYJy-fMKe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A channel is a synchronization mechanism. A write or read to an unbuffered channel will succeed only if there is another goroutine waiting to read/write from that same channel. Since you have an unbuffered channel and attempting to use channel as state storage, your first write blocks because there is no other goroutine reading from it.

Try with a channel with capacity 1:

```
stateMachine := make(chan int,1)
```

That will let writes work as long as the channel has storage.

Comment: I have accepted your answer but I don't know why my answer works. do you know why? Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61331885/1630827

Answer (score -1):

I do not know why but this works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

const (
    state1 = iota
    state2
    state3
    exit
)

func main() {
    stateMachine := make(chan int)
    go func() { stateMachine <- state1 }()
    for {
        select {
        case state := <-stateMachine:
            switch state {
            case state1:
                fmt.Println("state1")
                go func() { stateMachine <- state2 }()
            case state2:
                fmt.Println("state2")
                go func() { stateMachine <- state3 }()
            case state3:
                fmt.Println("state3")
                go func() { stateMachine <- exit }()
            case exit:
                fmt.Println("Exit")
                os.Exit(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/JH-w6SDCh-Z

Comment: Here, each write is done is a separate goroutine while the main goroutine continues. Each goroutine still waits to write to the channel until the main goroutine reads.

Comment: It can work, because you use the another goroutine to do the "write" action. One gorutine is blocked, don't affect another goroutine. they is controlled by the scheduler.